# Want to store info in the alpha channel but NOT have it blend the pixel

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, alphablending, opengl-es-3.0

This is regarding an SSAO buffer.  I'm storing the normals in RGB.  If I don't put 1.0 in A, it will blend the normals with what's already there as a normal alpha blend operation.

I want to store some additional info in the alpha buffer, and NEVER have it blend-- I want it always to blt the value of the pixel if it passes the z-test with no blending based on the contents of A.

Is it possible to do this with GLES 3.0?

tldr: I want every single pixel write to STAMP the pixel, and never blend based on alpha, always just write whatever values passed the z-test.

(Edit: Forgot to add, I'm already saying glDisable(GL_BLEND) beforehand... it still is blending the pixel, I can't seem to stop it)

Comment: "*I'm already saying glDisable(GL_BLEND) beforehand*" Are you certain of that? Also, how do you know that you're getting "blending" and not something else?

Comment: I'm displaying the resultant texture and I can see the overdrawn objects artifacted in rgb.  Is there anything besides GL_BLEND that might be overriding things here?

Comment: Multi-sampling and alpha-to-coverage is about the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Is it possible that your depth test isn't working well and you're seeing draw order or z-fighting artifacts?

Comment: I ended up giving up and doing everything a different way.